# Как определить индекс листа после поиска?

Tags: c#, list, find, c#-8.0

Есть вот такой лист

```
public class RegistrList : IEquatable<RegistrList>
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
   

    public long IdTelegram { get; set; }

    public string success { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ID: " + IdTelegram + " Login: " + Login + " succes: " + success;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        RegistrList objAsPart = obj as RegistrList;
        if (objAsPart == null) return false;
        else return Equals(objAsPart);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(IdTelegram);
    }
    public bool Equals(RegistrList other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.IdTelegram.Equals(other.IdTelegram));
    }
```

После определенных действий я нахожу нужный элемент в этом списке

```
RegistrList username = parts.Find((x) => x.IdTelegram == update.Message.Chat.Id);
                    string  fsd= Convert.ToString(username);                     
                    string[] subs = fsd.Split(' ');
```

А как мне можно узнать индекс найденного в листе элемента?

Comment: myList.FindIndex(a => a.Contains("Element")); - что то типа такого?

Comment: Да, вроде оно, спасибо)

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, но всё же: почему у вас Equals расписан так многословно? Можно же написать так: `public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is RegistrList rl && Equals(rl);` начиная с C# 7.0